# Bootstrap Table DATA-DATA-FIELD Not Changing ROWS

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm having an issue with bootstrap-tables. I don't know if I'm doing it wrong... or if it's a bug.

The 'data-data-field' seems to have no effect on changing the default 'rows' that are parsed within the json response.

The data is retrieved via the 'data-url' method, and attempting to add the param

```
<table 
  ...
  data-data-field="results" ... >
```

The response it is trying to parse is simplified below ...

```
{"count":"23433","next":"...","results":[{ "name":"demo", ... } ... ]}
```

Goal: Is to get 'results' as the array of rows instead of rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you should use, `data-field="results.name"` and so on...haven't tried using bootstrap-tables.

Comment: I have tried this :/ - back at it lol. thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to fix this issue.

In the table add the param.

```
data-side-pagination="server"
```

Script to add.

```
<script>
jQuery.fn.bootstrapTable.defaults.dataField='results';
</script>
```